# To prove : $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} g_t \ast f = 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $g_t(x) = e^{-x^2/2t^2}/t\sqrt{2\pi}$. To prove that for $f \in C_0(\mathbb{R})$, $$ \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} g_t \ast f = 0.$$ Is the question valid ? Any hints on how to solve it ?

Comment: Is $*$ the usual product?

Comment: the convolution, imo.

Comment: Substitution, $x = ty$.

Comment: @Git Gud : $\ast$ is convolution in $x$.

Comment: @Daniel Fisher : but $y$ is variable of integration.

Comment: Then call it differently. The point is to move the $t$ to the $f$.

Comment: @DanielFischer : Could you explain in the answer section ? I don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The family $g_t$ is a well-known convolution kernel. Most often, one considers the limit $t\to 0$, when $g_t$ converges (in the sense of distributions) to the Dirac measure, but the limit $t\to +\infty$ is also interesting (up to insignificant normalisation, $g_t$ is the [heat kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_kernel)).

When looking at the limiting behaviour for convolutions with a parametrised kernel family, it is often convenient to move the parameter from the kernel to the convolution partner, here too:

$$\begin{align}
(g_t\ast f)(x) &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty g_t(y)f(x-y)\,dy\\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{y^2}{2t^2}} f(x-y)\frac{dy}{t}\tag{$y = tz$}\\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-z^2/2} f(x-tz)\,dz.
\end{align}$$

Now we have one very well-behaved factor in the integrand that is independent of the parameter $t$, and we need to look at how $f(x-tz)$ behaves for $t\to \infty$. When doing that, remember Lebesgue.

Comment: Nice. Actually I think I have a way without using the symmetry of $\ast$. In which case we have to break the integral into two parts and estimate both of them. But your method is shorter and neater. So next step would be applying DCT ! Thanks. :)

Comment: But wait, $f$ may not be Lebesgue integrable !

Comment: We don't need that, $f$ is bounded (and continuous, hence measurable), so the integrand is dominated by $\lVert f\rVert_\infty \cdot e^{-z^2/2}$, which is integrable.

Comment: Ok, so I do not estimate exp term by 1, so I keep it as it is and together they form the recipe functions for DCT.